# MemSQL - how to create a column default with the current date?

Tags: singlestore

Getting this error when trying to create a table with a default value for a "_loaded_at" column:

ERROR 1067 (42000): Invalid default value for '_loaded_at'

This does not work:

```
CREATE TABLE json01(
id BIGINT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT
, _loaded_at DATETIME DEFAULT NOW()
, properties JSON NOT NULL
, SHARD KEY (id)
);
```

Whereas this does work:

```
CREATE TABLE json01(
id BIGINT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT
, _loaded_at DATETIME DEFAULT '1970-01-01 00:00:01'
, properties JSON NOT NULL
, SHARD KEY (id)
);
```

I also tried with the function UTC_TIMESTAMP().  Hoping that there is a way to specify a function as the default, since this is pretty standard functionality.  Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about considering something like:

```
_loaded_at TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

?

Comment: Yes, of all the date and time datatypes memsql supports only TIMESTAMP can default to the current timestamp on insert (DATETIME can't).